# jQuery DataTables with Select outside table

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is there a way an external drop-down could control the number of rows displayed in a DataTable page? We would set "sDom": l to show the inbuilt Select drop-down. But how can I use an external drop-down to do the same job?

Comment: follow custom filter example http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html

Comment: I think this is the route that I need to take. Now I need the exact DataTables API method to call, when the user selects a specific dropdown value in the Show xxx entries dropdown.

Comment: I got the answer here: http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnLengthChange

Answer (score 0):

You can write all lines inside of the table with $('table#tableID').html(allTableHTML); and with allTableHTML, you can do whatever you want to do. eg.

var allTableHTML + rowOne + rowTwo + rowThree;

and in the rows you can write for instance

var rowOne='Column 1Column 2';

So in the right order:

var rowOne='Column 1Column 2';
var allTableHTML + rowOne + rowTwo + rowThree;
$('table#tableID').html(allTableHTML);

Comment: not a good idea even considering using `html()` on the table and bypass the `datatables` API. API stores the row html and row data in internal data objects. API has all the necessary methods to accomplish what OP wants

Comment: i did not work with the datatables plug-in, jet. have to look into that.